# Svn add all files in repo

Tags: svn, git

What svn command is alternative `git add .` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn add .`

If you've got existing files and directories already in the repository, you probably want `svn add --force .` to make subversion continue to recurse through already-added directories.